# Java exception handling in multi-thread produced via wait() method

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, exception

I have this method in a class extending javax.swing.JPanel

```
private void waitForDone(){
    synchronized (lock){
        try {
            while(!done) lock.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
            log.error(SYNC_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

this method waits for the user to have done with the panel. Meanwhile, an ActionListener throws a custom exception. How can I handle it at this point?

Comment: you should handle the exception in a try/catch block in the void `actionPerfomed(ActionEvent e)` method. It has no relation with the lock and the `Object.wait()` method

Comment: In Swing, use a modal dialog.

Comment: why do you need while() loop? I think it would be better if you use CountDownLatch or Condition where you could call await/signal for the same purposes.

Comment: I can't handle the exception in the actionPerformed just because in that class I haven't access to enough information. I don't see how a modal dialog help, since I'm defining the behaviour of a button. I need the while loop because several objects share the same lock, so not all the calls of notify mean that the user has done.